# Flex TextInput doesn't accept the character ç

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

The Flex TextInput component does not accept "ç" characters. Could this be a flex or a font issue or has anybody recognized a similar problem=

regards

Cyrill

Answer (score 0):

Do you want that specific character to passed to server or by default it does not take it as input at all. Can i see your TextInput code.

Do check if your TextInput has some restrict or regular expression set which can also avoid such characters from taking as input.

Comment: Found a solution ... I'm using Myriad as font and the character ç was missing  in my imported swf file.